# SQL: count all records with consecutive occurrence of same value for each device set and return the highest count

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregation, data-analysis

I want to find out how many times a particular value occured consecutively for a particular partition and then display the higher count for that partition.

For Example if below is the table:

```
Device ID        speed             DateTime
--------------------------------------------------
07777778999       34               18-12-2016 17:15
07777778123       15               18-12-2016 18:10
07777778999       34               19-12-2016 19:30
07777778999       34               19-12-2016 12:15
07777778999       20               19-12-2016 13:15
07777778999       20               20-12-2016 11:15
07777778123       15               20-12-2016 9:15
07777778128       44               20-12-2016 17:15
07777778123       15               20-12-2016 17:25
07777778123       12               20-12-2016 17:35
07777778999       34                20-12-2016 17:45
07777778999       34               20-12-2016 17:55
07777778999       34               20-12-2016 18:50
07777778999       34               20-12-2016 18:55
```

---

I want to know for each device what is highest number of times the same speed appeared consecutively.

So if i partition them by device id, i would get the belo table

```
Device ID        speed             DateTime
--------------------------------------------------
07777778999       34               18-12-2016 17:15
07777778999       34               19-12-2016 19:30
07777778999       34               19-12-2016 12:15
07777778999       20               19-12-2016 13:15
07777778999       20               20-12-2016 11:15
07777778999       34                20-12-2016 17:45
07777778999       34               20-12-2016 17:55
07777778999       34               20-12-2016 18:50
07777778999       34               20-12-2016 18:55
07777778123       15               18-12-2016 18:10
07777778123       15               20-12-2016 9:15
07777778123       15               20-12-2016 17:25
07777778123       12               20-12-2016 17:35
07777778128       44               20-12-2016 17:15
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

So my required output would be like

```
Device ID        speed             highcount
--------------------------------------------------
07777778999       34               4
07777778123       15               3
```

note that 07777778128 did not appear as there were no values which repeated consecutively```

What would be the possible way to achieve this.
i was able to get the the count of all consecutive values for each device but then it doesn't give the highest rather gives count of all such consecutive groups

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a form of gaps-and-islands.  You can use a difference of row numbers to get the islands:

```
select device_id, speed, count(*) as num_times
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by device_id order by datetime) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by device_id, speed order by datetime) as seqnum_s
      from t
     ) t
group by device_id, speed, (seqnum - seqnum_s);
```

Then, to get the max, use another layer of window functions:

```
select device_id, speed, num_times
from (select device_id, speed, count(*) as num_times,
             row_number() over (partition by device_id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by device_id order by datetime) as seqnum,
                   row_number() over (partition by device_id, speed order by datetime) as seqnum_s
            from t
           ) t
      group by device_id, speed, (seqnum - seqnum_s)
     ) ds
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This worked! Many thanks.
The only problem is, it shows device id 07777778128 with num_times as 1 which eliminated by performing and with where to have num_times>1 (changed last line to where seqnum=1 And num_times >1)

Comment: Can the above be more simplified if i want to get the consective speed with value 1. Like i want to apply same thing to another problem where i have to find the highest count of consecutive records but in this case, the possible values of that column is just 0 or 1. so if i need to find for 1. i can use the same query but can it be made simpler for 1

Comment: @230490 . . . You should ask a *new* question, with sample data and desired results.