# SQL: Find count of rows with alternative 0's and 1's. Basically need to find the maximum count for such sequence

Tags: mysql, sql, data-analysis

This is related to another question asked here 
[SQL: count all records with consecutive occurrence of same value for each device set and return the highest count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59037783/sql-count-all-records-with-consecutive-occurrence-of-same-value-for-each-device/59037837#59037837)

But with a little difference. Let me explain with a table. In the table below, we need to get maximum count of all entries that follows the pattern 1 0 that is first on and then off again on and off etc. Basically, any device(device_id)which switches on and off consecutively needs to be retrieved with maximum count of 101010(counted as 3) pattern. 
The link about retrieves the same but with same consecutive value. That need to be tweaked to have 1 0 pattern

````
Device ID        on_off             DateTime
--------------------------------------------------
07777778999       1               18-12-2016 17:15
07777778123       1               18-12-2016 18:10
07777778999       1               19-12-2016 19:30
07777778999       1               19-12-2016 20:15
07777778999       0               19-12-2016 21:15
07777778999       1               20-12-2016 11:15
07777778999       0               20-12-2016 12:15
07777778999       1               20-12-2016 17:15
07777778999       0               20-12-2016 17:25
07777778999       1               20-12-2016 17:35
07777778999       0                20-12-2016 17:45
07777778999       0               20-12-2016 17:55
07777778999       0               20-12-2016 18:50
07777778999       0               20-12-2016 18:55
07777778999       1                20-12-2016 19:05
07777778999       0               20-12-2016 19:25
07777778999       1               20-12-2016 19:30
07777778999       0               20-12-2016 19:45
07777778123       1               28-12-2016 20:10
07777778123       1               28-12-2016 20:15
07777778123       1               28-12-2016 20:25
07777778123       1               28-12-2016 20:30
07777778123       0               28-12-2016 20:40

---------------------------------------------------------------- ```
so my expected table would be


```Device ID        max_cons_on_off       
-------------------------------
07777778999       4               
07777778123       1    ```
````

Comment: "pattern 1 0 that is first on and then off again on and off etc" - What is "*first*" for you? If you go by `DateTime`, then you get 2 for 07777778999 - not 4. See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3GJEeAsMhCavh7nTUXrCQT/0) with sorted data. Also please fix your DateTime format.

Comment: echoing @PaulSpiegel, not shown in the sample data is how the rows are to be ordered, why there's a device_id ..123 interspersed with ..999 rows,  does the occurrence of the ..123 device_id in that row sequence "break" the sequence of ..999 series? or is the intent to process the ..999 rows in order, without regard to interspersed other device id.  In the sample data shown, the datetime values for device_id ..999 are not in datetime order. So on what column or columns are rows to be ordered on?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel : If we go by date time we get 2 for 07777778999 but later if we keep seeing we again find the sequence of 1 0 10 10 10 starting at date 20-12-2016 19:05. The problem is to find the highest length of such sequence which is 4 in this case. By first i mean it should start with 1 and not 0 1 0 1

Comment: @spencer7593. They are currently ordered by date(because data keeps getting added as various devices keep generating data) and hence 123 device id appears. we need to group by device_id and then order by date and then apply our logic.

Comment: I get the same result reported by PaulSpiegel., The way the example data is presented, it looks like its a series of 4.  But when the rows are sorted on datetime, then there isn't a series of 4. The longest series is 2. (Take a look at that `9:15` row, its not in datetime order with the `11:15` row that precedes it. Which raises the question of what order those rows are in, because it's not datetime order, we can't get a series of 4 out of the sample data using datetime order. Why represent datetime values in a wonky non-canonical format?)

Comment: Sorry my bad, i messed up with datatime. Corrected it

Answer (score 0):

This seems more complicated.  My idea is to see where islands start by looking at the previous two rows.

```
select t.*,
       sum( case when oo_prev = 0 and oo_prev2 = 1 then 0 else 1 end) Over (partition by device_id order by datetime) as grp
from (select t.*,
             lag(on_off) over (partition by device_id order by datetime) as oo_prev,
             lag(on_off, 2) over (partition by device_id order by datetime) as oo_prev2
      from t
     ) t;
```

Then aggregate, filter, and aggregate again:

```
select device_id, max(cnt)
from (select device_id, count(*) as cnt
      from (select t.*,
                   sum( case when oo_prev = 0 and oo_prev2 = 1 and on_off = 1 and oo_next = 0 then 0 else 1 end) Over (partition by device_id order by datetime) as grp
            from (select t.*,
                         lag(on_off) over (partition by device_id order by datetime) as oo_prev,
                         lag(on_off, 2) over (partition by device_id order by datetime) as oo_prev2
                         lead(on_off, 1) over (partition by device_id order by datetime) as oo_next
                  from t
                 ) t
            ) t
     where on_off = 1 and oo_next = 0
     group by device_id, grp
    ) t
group by device_id;
```

Comment: Column 't.device_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.